# Django - access m2m objects (or raw pks) from ``clean`` before model is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

Of course you can't just use `self.related_field.objects.all()`, or you'll get a `...needs to have a primary key...` error, but if I want to run custom validation inside of `Model.clean`, there appears to be no way to access this data. Of course you can use `Form.clean` to do this, but I'm not always using forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible - the M2M records cannot exist until the main object has a primary key value. There is no way to access the data because it does not exist.